# MySQL How to convert second group by parameter results as a column?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

The following MySQL query result set repeats `MerchantID`:

```
select MerchantID,Category,SUM(Amount) 
group by MerchantID,Category 
from merchants
```

This will produce the following result:

```
MerchantID | Category | Total |

1           | gold     | 450  |
1           | silver   | 600  |
2           | gold     | 1120 |
2           | bronze   | 200  |
```

I want to get the result set like below:

```
MerchantID | gold | silver | bronze |

1           | 450  | 600    | 0      |
2           | 1120 | 0      | 200    |
```

I tried many queries but could not get such result. Please provide a solution for my problem. Thanks.

Comment: There is a syntax error in the initial query that should be fixed as well: `from` comes before `group by`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *conditional aggregation*:

```
select MerchantID, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'gold' THEN Total ELSE 0 END) AS gold,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'silver' THEN Total ELSE 0 END) AS silver,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'bronze' THEN Total ELSE 0 END) AS bronze 
from merchants
group by MerchantID
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2006b/3)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for example:

```
SELECT m.merchantId
    sum(if(m.Category='gold',m.total,null)) as gold,
    sum(if(m.Category='silver',m.total,null)) as silver,
    sum(if(m.Category='bronze',m.total,null)) as bronze
FROM merchants m
GROUP BY m.merchantId
```